# antlr: extract of a subtree with the antlr-treewalker as string

Tags: antlr

Is there an easy way to extract specific subtrees of an antlr tree after it has been checked for syntax?

For example if i checked an sql query and i only want the original whereclause with all whitespaces as string afterwards?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the parse tree construction not AST (ANTLR 3 or 4). Then the toString or getText methods can get you the text easily. ANTLR 4 is much better at this.

Comment: Can you give an short example for using "toString" or "getText" in ANTLR3 on a parser rule? I am using ANTLR3 because there are a lot more tutorials out there. Thanks

Comment: I tried: select returns [CommonTree ct] : ct= whereclause; and in the main.java ct.getText() or ct.toString(); both does not work it is always "nil" or "null" :(

Comment: sorry. you'll have to look at the api then. make tokenstream does the text stuff for ANTLR 4.